# Can't use function return value in write context in ... civicrm.php on line 342 (5.8.1, WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, installation

After manual installation of the plugin in Wordpress (5.0.1), PHP (7.2.12), mySQL (10.1.36-MariaDB). I can't activate it.

I receive this info:

Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in .../public_html/CRM/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php on line 342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be using an unsupported PHP version.  CiviCRM 5.8.1 requires PHP 5.6 or higher.

If this solves your problem, please mark it solved; if not, please edit your question to indicate your PHP version?

Comment: Added PHP version 7.2.12 and mySQL version as required.

Comment: @Wojtek That's odd - the PHP manual says that this construction only throws a fatal error in PHP versions less than 5.5: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php Are you sure about your PHP version? FWIW, there's a fix in the pipeline - you can apply it by changing the plugin code as per this PR: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-wordpress/pull/143

Comment: @ChristianWach thank you for the fix. In PHPmyAdmin I have  "PHP: 7.2.12". I applied it and tried to activate again. Then I've got:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in .../public_html/CRM/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php on line 894

Comment: @wojtek That's a sure sign that the PHP version running CiviCRM is older than 5.4.  I would check with your hosting provider - while it's unusual that two applications on the same server run different PHP versions it's certainly not impossible.

Comment: Thank you. It's solved. My hosting provider misled me about PHP version in CLI. It was 5.6 not 7.2. I changed it to 7.2. To make it work I had to change it also in .htaccess